# How to get the curvy node connector lines in the 2.80+ interface?

Tags: interface, compositing-nodes, theme, shader-nodes

This is a question about blender’s interface and the way it looks, with no functional difference.

I have windows 10, and when switching from blender 2.79 to 2.80 regardless of the machine, the curvy node connector lines for the shader and compositor became straight and boring. However, I keep seeing screenshots on Stack Exchange of users that obviously have 2.80+, but they have the nice curvy connector lines. How is this done?

Comment: @Gorgious yes. Now, how do I close my question as a duplicate…

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's called "Noodle Curving". It can be found in `Preferences > Themes > Node Editor`:

[image: Noodles]

Comment: Thanks so much! That is the right answer, but I have to wait 1 minute before I can tick it as such. God bless you and fam!